# List of int and floats in Python Polars casting to object

Tags: python, python-polars

Why does the column `floats` in the following example casts to `object` instead of `list[f64]`? How can I change it to `list[f64]`?

```py
import polars as pl

dfLists = pl.DataFrame({
    'ints':[ [0,1], [4,3,2]],
    'floats':[ [0.0,1], [2,3]],
    'strings':[ ["0","1"],["2","3"]]
})
dfLists
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌───────────┬──────────┬────────────┐
│ ints      ┆ floats   ┆ strings    │
│ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---        │
│ list[i64] ┆ object   ┆ list[str]  │
╞═══════════╪══════════╪════════════╡
│ [0, 1]    ┆ [0.0, 1] ┆ ["0", "1"] │
│ [4, 3, 2] ┆ [2, 3]   ┆ ["2", "3"] │
└───────────┴──────────┴────────────┘
```

Note: It seems this behavior may be new, based on this blog post ([.html](https://www.rhosignal.com/posts/polars-nested-dtypes/)) where the same example casts to `list[f64]`.

**Edit**: After updating polars to version `0.17.2` the column casts to `list[f64]` as expected.

I would still like to know if it is possible to change the dtypes of the elements of a list. For example, adapting the previous example:

```py
import polars as pl

dfLists = pl.DataFrame({
    'ints':[ [0,1], [4,3,2]],
    'object':[ [0,"1"], [2,3]],
    'strings':[ ["0","1"],["2","3"]]
})

dfLists.select(pl.col("strings").arr.eval(pl.element().cast(pl.Int16))) 
# works

dfLists.select(pl.col("object").arr.eval(pl.element().cast(pl.Int16))) # error
# error:
# PanicException: not implemented for dtype Object("object")
```

Comment: Just tried this code on the latest Polars version (0.17.2) and I get `list[f64]` on my end.

Comment: I'm using '0.16.1' on a Mac. I will try to update my version and report back.

Comment: It works with '0.17.2` and I updated my question.

Comment: I'm curious too.  Did you find a solution to your updated question?  If not, perhaps a new question about how to cast a Polars object might help.